# Unity Frustum culling Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, frustum, culling

I'm creating a game that utilizes off center projection. I've got my game set up in a CAVE being rendered in a cluster, over 8 PC's with 4 of these PC's being used for each eye (this creates a stereoscopic effect). To help with alignment in the CAVE I've implemented an off center projection class.

This class simply tells the camera what its top left, bottom left & bottom right corners are. From here, it creates a new projection matrix showing the the player the left and right of their world. However, inside Unity's editor, the camera is still facing forwards and, as a result the culling inside Unity isn't rendering half of the image that appears on the left and right screens.

Does anyone know of a way to to either turn off the culling in Unity, or find a way to fix the projection matrix issue?

Comment: Please don't misuse unity tag, as it is reserved by Microsoft Unity.

Comment: I see that it's been over a year since you asked this question -- may I ask if you ever found a solution? I have a similar issue where the frustum culling is behaving incorrectly because of some heavy transformations I am applying in my vertex shader. The transformations I am using don't play nicely with the mesh.bounds paradigm, as the world space position of each vertex impacts the extent of the transformation.

Comment: Yeah I did find something. However, I had to take out Unity pro support and the guys helped me there. Alas, I no longer have access to that code so I can't put it up. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this. You my find specific settings that address your issue there. Look to culling layers as well. Each layer can have its own culling distance. Maybe your camera setup is messing with them.

- [Camera.stereoConvergence](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-stereoConvergence.html)
- [Camera.stereoSeparation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-stereoSeparation.html)

Comment: Thanks man but this was asked 2 years ago when those things weren't in Unity. If you read my last comment above you'll discover that I found a fix but I had to go to unity pro support for it. Thank you though.